# How to compare two arrays to see how many same elements they have?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays, one is answers, and second one is correctAnswers and i need to see how many elements in answers are the same as in array of correctAnswers and to get percent how many "answers" are "correct". How do i do that? 
The arrays are something like this:

```
 answers = ["Hrtkovci","Lepenica","Dec"]

 correctAnswers = ["Lepenica","Dec","Leskovac"]
```

And i dont know if it matters but everything is with angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular.forEach to go through each item in both arrays and check if they are equal.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.answers = ["Hrtkovci", "Lepenica", "Dec"];
    $scope.correctAnswers = ["Lepenica", "Dec", "Leskovac"];

    $scope.compareArrays = function (arr1, arr2) {
        var inBoth = [];
        angular.forEach(arr1, function (a1) {
            angular.forEach(arr2, function (a2) {
                if (a1 == a2) {
                    inBoth.push(a1);
                }
            });
        });
        //return inBoth;
        var correct = 'You got ' + inBoth.length + '/' + arr2.length + ' answers!';
        var percentage = 'Correct: ' + ((inBoth.length / arr2.length) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        alert(correct + '\n' + percentage);
    };

    $scope.compareArrays($scope.answers, $scope.correctAnswers);

});
```

Edit: Sorry, didn't see you wanted correct answers and percentage. Updated Fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/7brtw543/1/)

Comment: its woorking!!Thank u!! :)

Comment: The complexity is N², it could be easily 2N instead with a map.

Answer (score 3):

```
var answers = ["Hrtkovci", "Lepenica", "Dec"],
    correctAnswers = ["Lepenica", "Dec", "Leskovac"],
    count = 0,
    percent;
correctAnswers.forEach(function (c) {
    if (answers.some(function (a) { return a === c; })) {
        count++;
    }
});
percent = count * 100 / correctAnswers.length;
document.write('Right Answers: '+count + ' Rate: ' + percent.toFixed(2) + ' %');
```

Comment: Because everybody gets at least one question right ? You could potentially show the user: "Right Answers: 0 Rate: Infinity%" - is that the intended outcome?

Comment: you mix up answers with correct answers. the correct answers is the base and this in not an empty array, because it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, you can loop overs answers and check them. With a forEach loop it would be :

```
var nbGoodAnswer = 0;
answers.forEach(function(answer, index, listAnswer){
    if(answer === correctAnswers[index]){
        nbGoodAnswer++;
    }
});
```

(It can be done with a simple `for` too)

Then :

```
console.log(nbGoodAnswer + " / " + answers.length +" bonnes réponses");
console.log((nbGoodAnswer / answers.length * 100) +"% bonnes réponses");
```

**Edit :** In another case, if your array of answers is not ordered or may not contain answers to all the questions :

```
var answer = [{question: 3, response: "C"}, {question: 1, response: "A"}];
var correctAnswer = [{question: 1, response: "A"}, {question: 2, response: "B"}, {question: 3, response: "C"}, {question: 4, response: "D"}];

var mapCorrectAnswerIdQuestion = {};
for ( var i = 0; i < correctAnswer.length; i++ ) {
    mapCorrectAnswerIdQuestion[correctAnswer[i].question] = correctAnswer[i].response;
}

// then you count
var nbGoodAnswer = 0;
for ( var j = 0; j < answer.length; j++ ) {
    if(answer[j].response === mapCorrectAnswerIdQuestion[answer[j].question]){
        nbGoodAnswer++;
    }
}
```

**Complexity : 2N** (answer.length + correctAnswer.length)

Comment: This assumes the arrays are equal and that they are in the same order

Comment: Exactly. You have to had a correct answer for each question/response.

Comment: He could have a list of question and the user could answer only some of them. Or the user could potentially answer them in a different order .. first question 2 then question 1 ... the questions could show up randomly .. .etc. A lot of things could vary, you're making too many assumptions

Comment: So you won't list strings like Branka said, because you need to identify the question. You have to list objects which contains an id and the answer. I will modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
array2 = ["Hrtkovci","Lepenica","Dec"]
array1 = ["Lepenica","Dec","Leskovac"]
var foo = [];
var i = 0;
jQuery.grep(array2, function(el) {
   if (jQuery.inArray(el, array1) == -1) foo.push(el);
   i++;
});
alert(" the difference is " + foo);
```

There are Other ways to achieve this.

You can see `.each` jQuery loop to traverse the arrays and compare them according to your choice.

but the above solution is clean and easy as jQuery is all doing this for us after all :D

Comment: your i variable isn't doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

## Try this

```
$answers =array("a"=>"Hrtkovci","b"=>"Lepenica","c"=>"Dec");

$correctAnswers =array("e"=>"Lepenica","f"=>"Dec","g"=>"Leskovac");

$result=array_intersect($answers ,$correctAnswers );

print_r($result);
```